# TPMS leaks air after tire replacement

Tags: tires

I have my four tires replaced on 2/16/2019 at Firestone Manchester CT. They are now Bridgestone tires. But about one month later, the low pressure indicator light on the dashboard was on. On 4/11/2019 I went to Firestone Norwich to do oil change and asked about the indicator. The guy at Norwich told me that the indicator was due to a frozen nut in the TPMS and I needed not to worry too much but would have to check the pressure regularly since the indicator light on would have no meaning. He set the indicator light off for me and put on the record a suggestion of replacement of TPMS, quoting 120 dollars.

4/26/2019, I found my left rear tire was deflated and I checked the air pressure and found it was less than 10 psi. After I put air back on the other day, the indicator light went off.

4/27/2019, I went to the Firestone Manchester and found the leakage around the valve, what is referred to as TPMS by Firestone staffs. When I was trying to figure out whether it was due to tire installation, the mechanic Tom Yang guffed up and told me they did not touch the TPMS part at all. When I was trying to complain about the Norwich branch for their misleading information, Yang arrogantly insisted that the suggestion Norwich gave was correct.

Actually, the Norwich guy made the right suggestion for the worng reason. He told me the indicator light was due to a malfunctioning TPMS (maybe expired battery) and **mentioned nothing about the leakage**. I feel lucky that I checked the tires and put back air on time. If I disregard the light as he suggested, I could have ruined the tire.

Another question I have is that is it possible that the leakage is because of a bad tire installation. Is the Firestone Manchester responsible for causing damage to my tire valve system? How should I verigy it?

Car info: 2014 Toyota Rav 4 LE.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don’t think either place is the cause of your leak - leaks happen with those as the fixing has more mass to secure compared to a standard valve assembly.